# I need to start an activity in service

Tags: android

now, I run a service, and I need this activity get the long press click listener to get the coordinate in other activity or home screen, and then start an activity to show the coordinate. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to Start New Activity and pass the value of co-ordinates in a bundle or as Intent extras

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Or 
From Solution Posted by [MarcinGil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5731/marcin-gil)

android.app.Service is descendant of android.app.Context so you can use startActivity directly. However since you start this outside any activity you need to set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag on the intent.

For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);       
where this is your service.
```

Answer (score 0):

just put following code on your oncreate() in your service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Your_Context, Your_Class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```